Why running fire shows a documentation?
Let's reproduce this with a simple script
import pandas as pd
import fire

def nada():

    data = {
      "calories": [420, 380, 390],
      "duration": [50, 40, 45]
    }

    #load data into a DataFrame object:
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fire.Fire(nada)

If we run this with python something.py (and be aware that for this to work Jinja2 needs to be installed!) the script does not finish but instead shows a "documentation file" like
NAME
    something.py - Two-dimensional, size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data.

SYNOPSIS
    something.py GROUP | COMMAND | VALUE

DESCRIPTION
    Data structure also contains labeled axes (rows and columns).
    Arithmetic operations align on both row and column labels. Can be
    thought of as a dict-like container for Series objects. The primary
    pandas data structure.

GROUPS
    GROUP is one of the following:

     T
       Two-dimensional, size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data.

     at
       Access a single value for a row/column label pair.

     attrs

     axes

     calories
       One-dimensional ndarray with axis labels (including time series).

     columns
       Immutable sequence used for indexing and alignment.

     dtypes
       One-dimensional ndarray with axis labels (including time series).

     duration
       One-dimensional ndarray with axis labels (including time series).

     flags

and we have to type q in order for this to finish
The reason is the return df in the function.
Why is this happening? And why documentation?

Isn't this the purpose of the fire library to turn the given object into a CLI? Sorry I'm just a bit confused

The help is telling you that you need to invoke it as something.py GROUP | COMMAND | VALUE…? I.e., without further instructions what you want it to do, it's just telling you what it can do, but you need to ask it to do one of those more specific things.

I'm no expert but it seems that fire can't serialize dataframes. If you specify the serialization like this:
    fire.Fire(nada, serialize=str)

then it outputs
   calories  duration
0       420        50
1       380        40
2       390        45

If that is what you want to achieve, then that's it :)
If that's not good enough then you may want to implement a custom serializer which handles basic data types AND dataframes.
You may want to keep an eye on this: https://github.com/google/python-fire/issues/532
